# Get each second 'td' element text contents , inside 'tr' elment

Tags: php, dom

i'm using `loadHTMLFile` to get the td contents of table from an HTML page , it is working perfectly ,

```
define('GLPI_ROOT', '..');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile(GLPI_ROOT . "/front/yourpage.html");
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table');
$table = $tables->item(9);
$ana = $table->getElementsByTagName('td');

foreach ($ana as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'td') {

    echo $td->nodeValue,"<br/>";


  }
}
```

but what i realy whant is only to get the second `td` element of each `tr` element in the `table`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$cnt= 0;
foreach ($ana as $td) {
  if ($td->nodeName == 'tr')
    $cnt= 0;
  else
    $cnt++;

  if ($td->nodeName == 'td' && $cnt == 2) {

    echo $td->nodeValue,"<br/>";
  }
}
```

Comment: tnks , but in `$ana` , i'm calling only the `td` elements `$ana = $table->getElementsByTagName('td');`